# Reading stuff from csv file without modules

Tags: python

How can I read a .csv file without the csv module or others? I have 2 files with movie names and actors to read. User needs to enter a name and return all actors from that movie. Is it possible without any modules?

Files:
all_movies.csv 
https://dox.abv.bg/download?id=960cefd34e

all_people.csv 
https://dox.abv.bg/download?id=13c9a04273

all_casts.csv 
https://dox.abv.bg/download?id=9fa805b24b

Comment: what did you try already? It is always better to have a starting point.

Comment: Provide your existing csv file format, or some examples on the same and also the expected output.

Comment: That is possible but correctly parsing the fields is not easy. Will any of your fields have a comma inside the field? If so, most csv's will wrap the field with quote marks, and just splitting the line on the commas will give a wrong result. There are many styles of csv--just which style are you using?

Comment: @Praveenkumar I've added the files.

Comment: @RoryDaulton I've added the files.

Comment: You can't do what you want with those files. The `all_movies.csv` file has some bad rows--for example, check the 24th row. More seriously, there is nothing that links the movies with the names. The two files seem completely separate. You need something that show which actors were in a given movie--the movies file does not have that information. But it is possible to read the csv files and remove the bad rows. If that is your question, make that more clear.

Comment: @RoryDaulton I've uploaded the last file I have. Can I still do the task with the bad rows?

Comment: It looks like I was wrong about the corruption in the movies file. My text editor mislead me into misunderstanding the foreign text in the movie name. As far as I can now see after looking more closely, the file is not corrupt, but I could be wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can read in those csv files without using any module, but it will be harder than using the `csv` or `pandas` or similar module. I'll give you some ideas here, but since you show no code of your own I will not show my own code. If you want code, attempt some of the things here and let us know what you tried.

Your first step is to understand just what you want to do. What is your user interface? What if the user types in a name that is used by multiple movies? What about movies or people that have multiple names (aliases)? And so on.

Your second step is to understand the data that you have. For example, the `all_movies.csv` is indeed a comma-separated file. Each row is text, I believe in UTF-8 encoding--some of the movie names are in Hebrew or Arabic. The lines are separated by a line-feed character (no carriage-return character). There are four fields in each row. Each field is surrounded with double-quote characters, with the exception of the value `\N` which seems to be a null marker. The fields are separated by a single comma with no space character. The first row is the header containing the field names: `"id","name","parent_id","date"`. You need the first two fields: a unique ID for each movie, given as a positive integer in decimal form, and the name, which may not be unique.

Your next step is to decide the data structures that will enable you to get what you want with a reasonable usage of time and memory. For example, you may want a dictionary where each key is the movie name whose corresponding value is a list of the IDs of movies having that name. (A [defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) would be better but that requires the `collections` module.) You probably do not need the other two fields in the `all_movies.csv` file. You also need a dictionary whose keys are movie IDs and values are lists of people IDs of people who were in the movie, and a dictionary whose keys are people IDs and values are the people names and perhaps other data about the people.

After you settle those decisions, at least temporarily, you can begin to code the routine that reads the movie file and creates the name-to-movie-IDs dictionary. You first open the text file and examine the first, header line as a sanity check. Then for each line you attempt to do this:

- Check that the first character of the line is a double-quote. If not, drop this line as a bad one.
- Search for the first double-quote character after the one already found. You can use Python's `find()` string method, using the `start` option to skip the double-quote already found.
- Ensure the text between those two double-quotes are all decimal digits, then convert to an `int` value.
- Ensure the next two characters after that last double-quote are a comma then another double-quote.
- Find the next double-quote.  While the character before that double-quote is a backslash `\`, convert the `\"` to just a `"` and search for the next double-quote character. This is needed since some movie names contain a double-quote, which is escaped in the file as `\"`. An example of that is `Making Frankensense of \"Young Frankenstein\"`, which has ID 3161.
- Save the text between the 3rd and 4th double-quote as the movie's name.
- Ignore the rest of the line (probably).
- Use movie name and ID to create a new dictionary key with that name, if needed, then append the ID to the list of movie IDs.

And so on. Do you get the idea? You cannot just split a text line on its commas, which is what the two current answers do, since some movie names contain commas (such as `Sonntag, im August` which has ID number 9). You need to break the lines on double-quotes, instead. An alternative to what I wrote above is to `split` the line on the double-quote character, then examine the resulting list of fields, but the escaped double-quotes and `\N` null marker would make that difficult.

Another alternative, one that I would look into, is to write a routine that scans just one field. It would distinguish between the null field and other fields, all o which start and end with double-quotes. That would run slower than what I outline above but would be usable to read the other two csv files. If you show some of your own work, I can show code that accomplishes this.

Answer (score 0):

Just parse it like you would a text file

```
with open('file.csv', 'r') as f:
    for line in f.read().splitlines():
        data = line.split(',')
```

Answer (score 0):

As a generator:

```
def readCSV(filepath, separator, header=false):
    with open(filepath, "r") as f:
        if header:
            yield next(f)
        for l in f:
            yield l.split(separator)
```

Where filepath is the file to read, separator is the token to split with and header is a flag to return the initial line as a header.

As an example call:

```
data = list(readCSV("file.csv", ";"))
```